# Custom Shipping Module not work on frontend in Magento v1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, shipping, shipping-methods

I had created a custom shipping module. But when I enable it and check on the frontend for my custom shipping rate, then I add billing detail and click on the Continue button, it redirects me to the cart page.

Here is the code of my custom shipping module.

> app/etc/modules/Custom_ShippingMethod.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_ShippingMethod>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Shipping />
            </depends>
        </Custom_ShippingMethod>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Custom/ShippingMethod/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_ShippingMethod>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Custom_ShippingMethod>
    </modules>
  <global>
        <models>
            <customshippingmethod>
                <class>Custom_ShippingMethod_Model</class>
            </customshippingmethod>
        </models>
        <helpers>
          <customshippingmethod>
            <class>Custom_ShippingMethod_Helper</class>
          </customshippingmethod>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <carriers>
          <customshippingmethod>
               <active>1</active>
               <model>shipping/carrier_customshippingmethod</model>
               <title>Custom Shipping Carrier</title>
               <name>My Custom Shipping Method</name>
               <price>5.00</price>
               <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            </customshippingmethod>
         </carriers>
       </default>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Custom/ShippingMethod/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <customshippingmethod translate="label" module="shipping">
                    <label>Custom Shipping</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <name translate="label">
                            <label>Method Name</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </name>
                        <price translate="label">
                            <label>Price</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </price>
                        <specificerrmsg translate="label">
                            <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </specificerrmsg>
                        <sallowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </sallowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        </specificcountry>
                    </fields>
                </customshippingmethod>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Custom/ShippingMethod/Model/Customshipping.php

```
<?php
class Custom_ShippingMethod_Model_Customshipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

    protected $_code = 'customshippingmethod';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $result->append($this->_getDefaultRate());

        return $result;
    }
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array(
            'customshippingmethod'=>$this->getConfigData('name')
        );
    }
    protected function _getDefaultRate()
    {
        $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $rate->setMethod($this->_code);
        $rate->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $rate->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
        $rate->setCost(0);

        return $rate;
    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Custom/ShippingMethod/Helper/Customshipping.php

```
<?php
class Custom_ShippingMethod_Helper_Customshipping extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

I got my custom shipping module configuration like this in admin. Please check the attached screenshot.
[image]

But on the frontend when I add the product to cart and go to checkout, after filliing up the billing info and click on "Continue" for Shipping Method. Then I am getting redirected on the cart page.

Can anybody suggest me where I am wrong.
I had reffered [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/14/magento-create-custom-shipping-method/) article.

Comment: did you check custom shipping also enable at store level ?

Comment: Yes @Pawan, I had checked the custom shipping method and it is enabled for all stores.

Comment: i checked your code, please see my answer. it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and found following error at:

> app/code/local/Custom/ShippingMethod/etc/config.xml

1. You need change `model` in `<customshippingmethod>` tag from `<model>shipping/carrier_customshippingmethod</model>` to `<model>shippingmethod/customshipping</model>`

**Explanation:** model name and path is wrong and it should be [modulename]/[path_to_model]

2. helper and model class should be in module tag i.e `<shippingmethod>` not `<customshippingmethod>`

I am attaching diff of file

[image]

Correct file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_ShippingMethod>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Custom_ShippingMethod>
    </modules>
  <global>
        <models>
            <shippingmethod>
                <class>Custom_ShippingMethod_Model</class>
            </shippingmethod>
        </models>
        <helpers>
          <shippingmethod>
            <class>Custom_ShippingMethod_Helper</class>
          </shippingmethod>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <carriers>
          <customshippingmethod>
               <active>1</active>
               <model>shippingmethod/customshipping</model>
               <title>Custom Shipping Carrier</title>
               <name>My Custom Shipping Method</name>
               <price>5.00</price>
               <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            </customshippingmethod>
         </carriers>
       </default>
</config>
```

Hope above will Help!

Comment: Hii @Pawan, Thanks for checking my code and providing me the solution to sort out my problem. I had applied your solution and changed the module tags for Model and Helper. But the problem doesn't get fixed. Still, I am facing the same issue with my custom shipping method.

Comment: just copy file i provided in answer, it will work.

Comment: I had copied and pasted your answer but still, it didn't get the solution for me. When I disable my custom shipping module the checkout shipping works fine and when I enable it again, then I am facing the same issue. I had checked my whole modules code 15 to 20 times and compared it with the blogs and google solutions. Also, I had applied your solution but I am facing the same issue. I am not getting where did I had made wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Pawan for giving me solution with explanation. Actually your solution is correct but I don't know why it does not provide a fix for my issue.

Comment: i can provide you whole code which is working for me , if you need.

Comment: Sure @Pawan. Please provide the code I will implement it in my module and check if it give solution. and let you know

Comment: please find whole code at https://github.com/pawankparmar/customshipping and let me know if have any issue.

Comment: Hello @Pawan, I implemented your code and It worked like a charm. Thanks for providing me the solution. I check and compared your code with my code and found that the code which I mentioned in the config.xml file and the model name in my system.xml were different. Also I didn't created a Carrier file in Model. I dont know why we had created the same files for Model and Carrier?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101866/discussion-between-mohammed-ubed-shaikh-and-pawan).

Comment: @MOHAMMEDUBEDSHAIKH, You can remove Carrier folder, it was just for testing.
we are not using that file anywhere.